# uploadify working in all browsers except firefox

Tags: javascript, uploadify

i've configured uploadify in my web application, it is working in all browsers except in firefox.

using .htpasswd

works fine for Http but didn't work for https

In firefox: IO error
Flash updated

Any suggestion would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: which version of uploadify are you working?

Comment: uploadify version 3.2